# Order MouseUp Event

Tags: javascript

This is a theoretical question... I have two mouseUp events. One of them is fired from a external jQuery plugin developed by other people that I'm using, this event is bound in this way:

```
//Add Events for mouse drag / touch swipe action
$(document).bind(self.event_up + self.id, { self: self }, self.mouseUp);
```

The other mouse up event, it's fired by me, using the standard code, something like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {

}

});
```

My question is easy, sometimes one event is fired before the other, and sometimes the other event is fired before the other one.

Can somebody explain me if I have any options to bind the mouseUp event in some order?

Comment: unbind these events and bind just a function to mouseup which calls manually yours and then the other

Comment: Can you add some code for that? Thanks, I don't know how can I exactly do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).unbind('mouseup');

$(document).bind(
                "mouseup",
                function( event ){
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    $.externalFunction(event);
                    yourFunction(event)
                }
            );
```

This is what you need.